# How to specify the domain of a variable?

Tags: variable-definitions, variable

How can I specify for every expression the domain of a variable without using assumptions everytime i have to simplify it?

Answer (score 3):

```
AddAssumption[assumption_]:=$Assumptions=DeleteDuplicates[$Assumptions&&assumption]
```

You need to also check which functions use $Assumptions by default. Simplify, Refine and FullSimplify use it.

To reset the assumptions use:

```
$Assumptions=True
```

Example:

```
AddAssumption[x>0]
Simplify[Sqrt[x^2]]

Out: x
```

Comment: So if x must be a real variable for every expression i write how can I do?

Comment: AddAssumption[Element[x, Reals]]

Comment: Well, thank you it works very well