# How to specify the domain of a parameter?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, parameters

There is a similar post: [How to specify the domain of a variable?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75984/how-to-specify-the-domain-of-a-variable), but it doesn't work well for me.

I want to evaluate  the integral below, with a parameter $\gamma$. The result is obviously different depending on $\gamma>1/2$ or $\gamma<1/2$. I tried the "AddAssumption" method in that post, but it doesn't work out. It gives the result for $\gamma<1/2$ either way.

```
$Assumptions = True
AddAssumption[assumption_] := $Assumptions = DeleteDuplicates[$Assumptions && assumption]
AddAssumption[\[Gamma] > 1/2]
Integrate[1/(\[Gamma] + 1/2 Cos[2 \[Phi]]), \[Phi]]
```

Comment: The claim "The result is obviously different depending on $ \gamma>1/2$ or $\gamma<1/2$" does not correspond to `Integrate[1/(\[Gamma] + 1/2 Cos[2 \[Phi]]), \[Phi]]` which produces a generic answer $$-\frac{2 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{(2 \gamma -1) \tan (\phi )}{\sqrt{1-4 \gamma ^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{1-4 \gamma ^2}}$$

Comment: I don't agree. $\gamma>1/2$ obviously gives a complex number for the denominator. Are you arguing that the result is generic in the sense we do a series of complex analysis?

Comment: `Simplify[D[-((2 ArcTanh[((-1 + 2 \[Gamma]) Tan[\[Phi]])/
         Sqrt[1 - 4 \[Gamma]^2]])/Sqrt[1 - 4 \[Gamma]^2]), \[Phi]]]` results in `2/(2 \[Gamma] + Cos[2 \[Phi]])`.

Comment: @user64494 Try $\gamma =1$, which gives $\frac{2\arctan{\frac{\tan(\frac{x}{2})}{\sqrt{3}}}}{\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: @user64494 So you are arguing that this result is generic in the sense of complex analysis while I just want a simplied real expression.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand you. An antiderivative of a real-valued function may be a complex-valued function. That was discussed at this forum many times.

Comment: @user64494 I am a math major and know those stuff. Look, the thing is, there is a valid real expression for $\gamma>1/2$ as in the case $\gamma=1$, and I want that real expression. It is not hard actually for me to derive it by hand through some trigonometry but I just want to know how to ask Mathematica handle it to save my effort in the future.

Comment: See the result of `\[Gamma] = 1; Plot[{Re[ (2 ArcTanh[((-1 + 2 \[Gamma]) Tan[\[Phi]])/
        Sqrt[1 - 4 \[Gamma]^2]])/Sqrt[1 - 4 \[Gamma]^2]], 
  Im[ (2 ArcTanh[((-1 + 2 \[Gamma]) Tan[\[Phi]])/
        Sqrt[1 - 4 \[Gamma]^2]])/
    Sqrt[1 - 4 \[Gamma]^2]]}, {\[Phi], -Pi, Pi}]`. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: @user64494 You are still arguing something that I agree. I KNOW that they are equivalent if you put $\gamma =1$ inside the denominator and do some algebra to show that the imaginary part is 0 and the real part is what we want. BUT, the thing is, it HAS a real expression (see my comment above), and I want Mathematica to get this real expression.

Comment: @Apocalypse  your "γ==1 obviously gives a complex number for the denominator." is true, but numerator is also complex, so it cancels. `2 I ArcTan[Tan[\[Phi]]/Sqrt[3]] ` / `I Sqrt[3] `

Comment: @Akku14 I know that they cancel. So there is a real expression for the case $\gamma>1/2$, right? Then how to ask Mathematica to show that real expression?

Comment: Maple allso produces the same result as Mathematica which does not depend on the cases $|\gamma| \le 1/2$ or $|\gamma| > 1/2$ .

Comment: I just did a calculation by hand, and the result is $\frac{\frac{2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{4 \gamma +2} \tan \left(\frac{\phi }{2}\right)+2}{\sqrt{4 \gamma -2}}\right)}{\sqrt{\gamma -\frac{1}{2}}}-\frac{2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2-\sqrt{4 \gamma +2} \tan \left(\frac{\phi }{2}\right)}{\sqrt{4 \gamma -2}}\right)}{\sqrt{\gamma -\frac{1}{2}}}}{2 \sqrt{\gamma +\frac{1}{2}}}$. It seems Mathematica tries to get the common denominator automatically.

Comment: @user64494 See the result I got by hands above. I guess Mathematica just does an "illegal" (in the sense if we don't have complex number) simplification for the two numerators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un uncommon trick (for a mathematical expert) does it:

```
Integrate[1/(EulerGamma + 1/2 Cos[2 \[Phi]]), \[Phi]] /. 
     EulerGamma -> \[Gamma]

(*   (2 ArcTan[((-1 + 2 \[Gamma]) Tan[\[Phi]])/Sqrt[-1 + 4 \[Gamma]^2]])/
      Sqrt[-1 + 4 \[Gamma]^2]   *)
```

Comment: Both the numerator and denominator are complexvalued if `RealAbs[\[Gamma]] < 1/2`. All you derive by this incorrect trick is `ArcTan` instead of `ArcTanh`.

Comment: @user64494 , You know very well that this is only intented and valid for RealAbs[gamma] greater than 1/2 because EulerGamma >1/2 and it is absolutely correct for this case (you can further test with Reduce or else, so the trick can be validated.). So please save your comments if you don't have a better solution. Thanks for the -1, if from you!?

Comment: I made the observation, that this trick with definite numbers works in more than a few cases. ------------------Let me give a general statement:-----------------This mehtod works and can only work, if and because MMA already knows the underlying rules to solve it. I think, for undefined parameters, it has problems with the test routines for validity ranges, mainly for parameter values up to infinity.------------------------------ Of course, if you got a result, you have to test for validity ranges with other methods, means you have in parts do the job MMA does not in that case.

Answer (score 5):

It is indeed possible to get a real antiderivative, but you need to use the [Rubi](https://rulebasedintegration.org) package (easy to install).

```
<< Rubi`
```

Now we consider 3 cases

```
Assuming[γ>1/2,Int[1/(γ+1/2 Cos[2 ϕ]),ϕ]]
```

$$\frac{2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{-\frac{1-2 \gamma }{2 \gamma +1}} \tan (\phi )\right)}{\sqrt{4 \gamma ^2-1}}$$

```
Assuming[-1/2<γ<1/2,Int[1/(γ+1/2 Cos[2 ϕ]),ϕ]]
```

$$\frac{2 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-2 \gamma }{2 \gamma +1}} \tan (\phi )\right)}{\sqrt{1-4 \gamma ^2}}$$

```
Assuming[γ<-1/2,Int[1/(γ+1/2 Cos[2 ϕ]),ϕ]]
```

$$\frac{2 \sqrt{-\frac{2 \gamma +1}{1-2 \gamma }} \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{-\frac{1-2 \gamma }{2 \gamma +1}} \tan (\phi )\right)}{2 \gamma +1}$$

Comment: Very nice packages! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question. The result is this ugly monster $$\frac{\frac{2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{4 \gamma +2} \tan \left(\frac{\phi }{2}\right)+2}{\sqrt{4 \gamma -2}}\right)}{\sqrt{\gamma -\frac{1}{2}}}-\frac{2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2-\sqrt{4 \gamma +2} \tan \left(\frac{\phi }{2}\right)}{\sqrt{4 \gamma -2}}\right)}{\sqrt{\gamma -\frac{1}{2}}}}{2 \sqrt{\gamma +\frac{1}{2}}}$$ and Mathematica just tries to simplify it (by introducing complex quantities).

Originally I thought there should be a nice real expression, as in the case of $\gamma=1$, but Mathematica kept giving me a "complex" result. It turns out now, as we see the expression is horrible if we put it into real numbers by force, that Mathematica is really trying to get the answer as simple as possible by making it complex.

---

An update on the result. The expression above could be simplified significantly (to get the one in other answers). The best way to integrate this thing is through the following trig-substitution
$$\int\frac{1}{\gamma+\frac{1}{2}\cos2\phi}d\phi=\int\frac{\sec^2\phi}{1+(\gamma-\frac{1}{2})\sec^2\phi}d\phi=\int\frac{d(\tan\phi)}{1+(\gamma-\frac{1}{2})(1+\tan^2\phi)}$$

I chose a much more stupid way when I evaluated for the first  time and ended up with the monstrous result above.

Comment: Your answer is incomplete as the domain is not specified. Please see my answer

Comment: @yarchik My answer is intended for the $\gamma>1/2$ case, which is also the one I need.